# Retrieve top five opportunities from CRM using C#

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011

I have written code for retrieving the Opportunity entity from dynamics CRM, is there any way I can retrieve only top five entities based on the revenue ?

Comment: Surely you can. Please show your current code

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
            QueryExpression query_ = null;
            RetrieveMultipleRequest requests_ = null;

            query_ = new QueryExpression();
            query_.EntityName = "opportunity";
            query_.ColumnSet = new ColumnSet(true);
            query_.Orders.Add(new OrderExpression("estimatedvalue", OrderType.Descending));
            query_.PageInfo.Count = 5;
            query_.PageInfo.PageNumber = 1;


            requests_ = new RetrieveMultipleRequest();
            requests_.Query = query_;
            EntityCollection collection = _sdk.RetrieveMultiple(requests);
```

Answer (score 1):

In query expression you can set

```cs
queryExpression.PageInfo.Count = 5;
```

Don't forget put a specific order, in a FetchXml you can set like that:

```xml
<fetch mapping="logical" count="0" version="1.0">
```